# Installing MS SQL Server 2008 R2 side by side with MS SQL 2008 R2 Express edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have to install full version of MS SQL 2008 R2 (it's Web edition) side by side with MS SQL 2008 Express (for a short period, before migrating all db's to full version).

I guess that it can be tricky/dangerous under some circumstances, so I'd like to ask You for hints or tactics to apply in such situation (ie. should I uninstall something from express, should I upgrade something, can there be problems with moving databases, etc.)

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I guess that it can be
>   tricky/dangerous under some
>   circumstances

Ah. No. This is called an instance, and installing multiple instances of SQL Server is fully supported. You can even install 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2 on the same computer.

Just install. Basically Express has a specific predetermined instance name. Unless you choose the same byforce, the installation wil lbe side by side.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad that there should be no trouble with it :)